# Docker container not connecting to remote HBase

Tags: python, docker-compose, dockerfile, hbase

I had created a docker-container of python application where the code in it tries to connect to remote HBase cluster hosted on Cloudera.

Docker is running fine,except that, it is not doing read/write operation on remote HBase.

Here is my part of docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: python3 app.py
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - "8007:8007"
```

Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: since your docker container seems to run fine, i doubt the issue is with you docker-compose file. did you check the database on cloudera is accessible (from wherever your container runs)? have you tried accessing your db with a standard sql client (not via your app)?

Comment: hi @mrxra , remote hbase-cluster is accessible from the server where container runs.
Moreover , I am able to do telnet to hbase inside the container even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue ,this is because at remote HBase-cluster, thrift server was not accessible by docker.

Whitelisting my docker IP at HBase-cluster solved the issue.